# Scheduled task completes but doesn't run application

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule my application to run every hour. I have done this numerous times before but this time is proving problematic.

The task runs and says it is completed but it doesn't launch my application. It doesn't even display the message I have set. I even set the action to only display the message and it still doesn't work. I've changed the user that runs it, even though we are all admin on the machine.

What could be wrong? What other debug steps could I take? Seeing as the task says it completes, and it has an event saying it has launched the application, surely it should have worked?

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the person who requested a close above, it turned out it WAS a programming issue.

The task ran correctly when the security level was set to "Run only when user is logged in" but wouldn't run when set to "Run whether user is logged in or not". This was due to me using a mapped drive location in code. I change the mapped drive to the absolute path and it now works successfully.